# ¿como enviar correo automático (gmail) cuando autorizo un registro desde un checkbox?

Tags: javascript, php, html, angularjs

Este es mi script con el que autorizo la orden de compra.

```
    <script>
         $('#table2').on('check.bs.table', function (e, row) {
          //    print_r(row);
           location.reload()
           angular.element($('#requisicionID')).scope().aprobar(row);
         });

         $('#table2').on('uncheck.bs.table', function (e, row) {

          console.log(row);
          });
         </script>
```

Y este es el angular donde se aprobó y se autorizo la orden de compra:

```
 $scope.aprobar = function(obj) {
    $http.get(urlOrdenes + 'autorizarCompraID/' + obj.idCompra).success(function(data) {
        $scope.set_flashdata('Se autorizo la orden de compra correctamente!', 'success');
            $scope.loadData();
    });
};
```

Lo que quiero que después que se autoriza la orden de compra, automáticamente se mande un correo gmail con el idCompra de la orden de compra que autorizo.

[image: se debe mandar el correo al dar click en el checkbox del registro seleccionado]

Comment: Hola, que haz intentado hasta ahora?

Comment: pues la verdad solo e enviado correo a través de php pero ingresando los datos en caja de texto y mandándolo desde un botón, no que se envié automático, no tengo ni idea de como hacerlo cualquier idea que tengan la probare.

Comment: apenas estoy investigando y se me ocurrio hacer la pregunta xD.

Comment: Quieres enviar el mail desde javascript o desde php?

Comment: desde javascript amigo sioesi, si tienes alguna idea asmela saber por favor .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para enviar desde javascript un mail desde gmail debes implementar la api de google para esta funcion.

1. Lo primero que debes hacer es crear tus credenciales en la consola de desarrollador de google.
2. Debes crear las variables de cliente id y la key que te entrega la consola.
3. Declarar los scope que son las url que vas a consultar `var scopes =
   'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly '+
   'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send';

Te dejo un completo tutorial de esto, obviamente debes adaptarlo a tu ejemplo, esta en ingles pero basta con traducir la web y entenderlo.

[tutorial send mail gmail](https://www.sitepoint.com/sending-emails-gmail-javascript-api/)

**EDICION**

La variable se encuentra en el valor que envias por get a tu url, por lo tanto puedes manejarla tanto desde angularjs como desde php

Comment: Creo que no me explique del todo, correos si se mandar lo que no se es como debe ser el código para que me jale el dato idCompra de la orden que se autoriza y en automático se envié el correo sin llenar ningún campo manualmente.

Comment: Aaah!!! Pero eso es sencillo, como generas el idCompra?

Comment: ` function autorizarbyID($idCompra){
          $this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE)  if($this -> db ->           query("update ordenescompra SET NomUser =         ". $this->user-   >info->ID .", statusAut = 'false', FechHoraAut = now() WHERE   idCompra = ?;", $idCompra)){
        return 'actualizado';
      }
    }`

Comment: Pero a ver, sigo sin entender desde donde quieres enviar el email, si desde tu angularjs le permites enviar la idCompra a tu Url que lo recibe como get, ahi tienes el valor que buscas?? Si es de php lo recibes en la url y haces el mismo update de la base de datos, no entiendo cual es el problema?

Comment: ok sioesi ya me diste la clave ya se como hacerle, tienes mucha razón intentare probar así, es que angularjs apenas lo estoy probando y aun no comprendo mucho xD, Gracias por tiempo!!

Comment: Cualquier duda me comentas, no hay ningun problema!